# Python file data position

Tags: python

The problem I am facing is that I need to find the position of a string

Code:

`file = open('data.txt', 'r')`

`print file.read`

data.txt contains
`"banana", "mango", "apple", "pear", "dragon fruit"`

For example how do I find the position of the string `"mango"`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the the code you wrote yet, and your efforts 
about solving this problem, so we can reproduce and help about a specific question or errror.
See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the position of the word within the file using `index`. Try the following:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
      content = f.read()
      print content.index('mango')
```

This would return the index of the word if it exists or give an error if it doesn't find the word within the file.

Comment: Thanks! You see I am only in middle school and I don't know that many built-in python functions.

Comment: No worries! You can always use SO as a learning curve when you run into any problems! Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the built-in string find() function:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Answer (score 0):

Try str.find()

So for mango:

```
with open(file, 'r') as r:
    data = r.read()

print(data.find('mango'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've several more lines in the CSV file like this.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fin.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        result = [item.replace('"','').strip() for item in line.split(',')]
        print(result.index('mango'))
```